# Codeigniter 3, ion_auth and 404s

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm setting up Codeigniter 3 with ion_auth for the user system. It should be a straightforward install, but I am getting nothing but 404s when calling the auth controller. I must be missing something obvious, but I can't see it.

The basics are:
`$config['base_url']    = 'http://russellbits.com/labs/codeigniterlab/';`
That's my server and the local file I've put everything in

`$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`
For the moment I'm avoiding the .htaccess file (until I figure out these 404s)

If I call either
`http://russellbits.com/labs/codeigniterlab/index.php/auth/login` or
`http://russellbits.com/labs/codeigniterlab/index.php/`

The login and main pages show up fine. Once I try to log in though, I get

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /public/index.php was not found on this server.

Double-checking the URL, the system is calling
`http://russellbits.com/labs/codeigniterlab/auth/login` <- Note: no index.php

And I don't know where the system is getting the idea that it needs to call the /public folder. That folder neither exists nor is in any of the config files. Any thoughts?

Comment: in codeigniter the file name must have first letter capital eg. if you controlelr fille name is auth.php name in Auth.php , than it will work

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm aware of that detail (and have had that problem before) but in this particular case, changing the capitalization doesn't help.

Comment: A .htaccess file in one of the parent directories is most likely modifying your requests.

Comment: did you find any answer? I am facing the same problem and i am having no .htaccess in root

Comment: did you check the link if that shows the right url? or the form action?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `config/routes.php` and make sure you **don't** have a rule like below:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```